# Can't fetch data from Supabase table

Tags: react-native, supabase, supabase-database

I have been trying to fetch data from `Supabase` but I couldn't. So I have two screens - one for managing the input(the input data successfully goes to the database) and one where the data should render as text.

Here is the managing screen:

```js
const ManageResume = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [education, setEducation] = useState('');
  const [workExperience, setWorkExperience] = useState('');
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState('');
 

  const handleSaveResume = async () => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.from('profiles1').insert([
        {
          name,
          phoneNumber,
          email,
          education,
          workExperience,
          skills
        },
      ]);

      if (error) {
        Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Success', 'Resume saved successfully');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving resume:', error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
            <ScrollView>
      <Input
        label="Name"
        value={name}
        onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
      />
        <Input
        label="Phone number"
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPhoneNumber(text)}
      />
        <Input
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
      />
        <Input
        label="Education"
        value={education}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEducation(text)}
      />
        <Input
        label="Work experience"
        value={workExperience}
        onChangeText={(text) => setWorkExperience(text)}
      />
        <Input
        placeholder="Skills"
        value={skills}
        onChangeText={(text) => setSkills(text)}
      />
      <Button title="Save Resume" onPress={handleSaveResume} />
      </ScrollView>

  );
};
```

Here is the other screen where the information should be rendered, but it does not show on the screen:

```js
function ProfileScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const user = supabase.auth.getUser();

        if (user?.id) { 
          const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('profiles1') 
            .select('*')
            .eq('user_id', user.id)
            .single();

          if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching user information:', error.message);
          } else {
            setUserInfo(data);
          }
        } else {
          setUserInfo(null);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user information:', error.message);
      }
    };

    const authListener = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      fetchUserInfo();
    });

    fetchUserInfo();

  }, []);

  return (
      {userInfo && (
        <View>
          <Text>Name: {userInfo.name}</Text>
    
          {/*other user information here */}
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I don't know where the problem could be. I have `user_id` column with the type `uid` in the database which gets inserted automatically. This is my first time using `Supabase`, and gets confusing at times. If someone has any idea where the problem could be, thank you!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I'm getting this ' Error fetching user information: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "undefined"'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add relevant information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`getUser()` is an async function, so you have to `awiat` it.

```js
const user = await supabase.auth.getUser();
```